# How to split `NSmutableArray` array array to chunks swift 3?

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

```
NSMutableArray *sample;
```

I have an `NSmutableArray`, and I want to split it into chunks. I have tried checking the internet didn't find the solution for it. I got the link to split integer array.

Comment: Please update question with reference `NSMutableArray` and expected `output` .

Answer (score 2):

How about this which is more Swifty?

```
let integerArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
let stringArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
let anyObjectArray: [Any] = ["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3]

extension Array {
    func chunks(_ chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: chunkSize).map {
            Array(self[$0..<Swift.min($0 + chunkSize, self.count)])
        }
    }
}

integerArray.chunks(2) //[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
stringArray.chunks(3) //[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]
anyObjectArray.chunks(2) //[["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]
```

To Convert `NSMutableArray` to Swift `Array`:

```
let nsarray  = NSMutableArray(array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
if let swiftArray = nsarray as NSArray as? [Int] {
    swiftArray.chunks(2) //[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
}
```

If you wanna insist to use `NSArray`, then:

```
let nsarray  = NSMutableArray(array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

extension NSArray {
    func chunks(_ chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: chunkSize).map {
            self.subarray(with: NSRange(location: $0, length: Swift.min(chunkSize, self.count - $0)))
        }
    }
}

nsarray.chunks(3) //[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
```

Comment: Nope its for integer array not for nsmutablearray or nsarray

Comment: @technoAndroid You can convert NSMutableArray to Swift Array...... I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for the help brianlikeApple but i need nsmutablearray itself..for specific purpose i am using it

Comment: @technoAndroid I have updated the answer! Nothing can stop you :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subarray` method.

```
let array  = NSArray(array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

let left  = array.subarray(with: NSMakeRange(0, 5))
let right = array.subarray(with: NSMakeRange(5, 5))
```

Comment: can you provide me solution in swift 3

Comment: i am getting range  extends beyond bounds.how to handle it.if der is no index

Comment: my array range is 772.but it gives error that index range {392, 441} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 772]'..